# can mysql_fetch_array get mysql_query as argument?

Tags: php, mysql

can I use `mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('...'))`?

or is that the only way:

`$res = mysql_query($sql);
    $data = array();
    while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) !== false) {
       $data[] = $row;
    }`

NOTE that I'm expecting only ONE row/result

Comment: Those are the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, yes (if you expect only one row returned), **but you probably shouldn't**.

It is important to check the success or failure of `mysql_query()` before attempting to fetch a result from it. If `mysql_query()` fails, it will pass `FALSE` to `mysql_fetch_array()`, and that will result it in an error like

```
 mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given..
```

It is much safer to assign the output of `mysql_query()` to a variable which is a result resource, and test its success or failure.

In any case you *cannot* do `mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query(...))`  if you expect more than one result returned.